# python program for round robin tournament

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that allows the user to enter and even number of players and then it will generate a round robin tournament schedule. `n/2 * n-1` number of games so that each player plays every other player.

Right now I'm having a hard time generating the list of the number of players the user enters. I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: 'int' object not iterable.

I get this error a lot in my programs, so I guess I'm not quite understanding this part of Python, so if someone could explain that as well, I'd appreciate it.

```
def rounds(players, player_list):
    """determines how many rounds and who plays who in each round"""
    num_games = int((players/2) * (players-1))
    num_rounds = int(players/2)
    player_list = list(players)
    return player_list
```

Comment: How are you calling `rounds`?

Comment: well rounds are how many games can be going on at the same time, so n/2

Comment: what do you intend to do with `list(players)` ??

Comment: I'm trying to get a list so that if there are 4 players, player_list=[1,2,3,4]. i haven't quite figured out what to do after that, but for the round robin algorithm it seems to be useful to have a list of the players

Comment: Sounds like you want [`itertools.combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) If you can't work out how to generate a list of numbers, you need to look over some basic Python tutorials first.

Comment: is there a way to do it without using itertools.combinations()? Like if you have the list of the players, a way to match up the first and last, and the second and the second-to-last, etc, but without knowing how many players there will be in the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to get a list of numbers, you probably want the [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) function.

For an actual round-robin tournament, you should look at [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
>>> n = 4
>>> players = range(1,n+1)
>>> players
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(itertools.combinations(players, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: That does help me generate the list, but it includes 0.  I now have: player_list= list(range(players))  How do I do this starting with 1? I'm sure it's really easy but I'm new to lists and I'm not sure

Comment: `range(x,y)` generates a range of numbers from `x` to `y-1` (whereas `range(y)` generates a range of numbers from `0` to `y-1`).

Comment: it says that global name itertools is not defined

Comment: @tinydancer9454 because you need to `import itertools`. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
player_list= list(players)
```

Is what raises the `TypeError`. This is happening because the `list()` function only knows how to operate on objects that can be iterated over, and `int` is not such an object.

From the comments, it seems like you just wanted to create a list with the player numbers (or names, or indices) in it. You can do it like this:

```
# this will create the list [1,2,3,...players]:
player_list = range(1, players+1) 
# or, the list [0,1,...players-1]: 
player_list = range(players) #  this is equivalent to range(0,players)
```