# python matching up items in a list to create new lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a program that creates a round robin tournament schedule (every player plays every other player) for a certain number of players.
I was wondering if there was a way to do this using just lists.  I'm trying not to use itertools.combinations()

Can anyone think of a way to do this if I have a program that allows you to input the number of players and generates a list of those players? 
Example: 4 players generates the list [1,2,3,4]

I need the program to print:

Round 1:  1 vs. 4   2 vs. 3

Round 2:  1 vs. 3   4 vs. 2

Round 3:  1 vs. 2   3 vs. 4

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353038/python-program-for-round-robin-tournament

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple implementation of the first algorithm described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm).

```
N = 6
a = range(N)
for i in xrange(N-1):
    print zip(a[:N/2], reversed(a[N/2:]))
    a = a[:1] + a[-1:] + a[1:-1]
```

EDIT: actually, as pointed out, it even works for odd `N`s.

(ORIG: This only works if `N` is even.  The link explains how to extend it to support odd `N`s.)